# How to fix automatic logout problems,when a new user login in php

Tags: php

How do i fix automatic logout problems,when a new user login into the system.i also used two machine to test my login and logout, but it keeps one user logged out when a new user login...please help

```
  switch ($row["status"]) {
        case 'Admin':
            session_id('admin');
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['Ausername'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['Auser_id'] = $user_id;
            $_SESSION['Amycompany'] = $seleCompany;
            if (isset($username)) {
                setcookie('Administrator',$username,time()+60*60*7);
            }
            $_SESSION['success'] = " Welcome " . $username . "  to PSL Lunch";
            header('Location:persol/admin/index.php');
            break;

        case 'Member':
            session_id('member');
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
            $_SESSION['mycompany'] = $seleCompany;
            if (isset($username)) {
                setcookie('Member',$username,time()+60*60*7);
            }
            $_SESSION['success'] = "Welcome " . $username . " to PSL Lunch";
            header('Location:persol/member/index.php');
            break;

        default:
        $_SESSION['warning'] = "Username or Password is incorrect";
        header('Location:index.php');
    }
```

## my login php script for both the admin and member page

Comment: The best advice I could give for you is to do this, that, and the other thing. Anymore specific of an answer would require some code and/or effort on your part. Please review the SO help for guidance on how to ask a good, *solvable*, question.

Comment: Okay..,i just added the login script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a couple things here, the main one being I wouldn't mess with the `session_id()` except maybe to reset it after log in. There are other ways to indicate user type. You can store the `usergroup` in the session. Secondly, I would use the `$_SESSION` to save the activity time instead of cookies. Users can turn cookies off in their browser. Lastly, I would make some useful functions to help keep things less repetitive and more reusable:

**/functions/myfunctions.php**

```
# Create a login function
function logInUser($username,$seleCompany,$isAdmin = false)
{
    # Save type here
    $_SESSION['usergroup'] = ($isAdmin)? 1 : 2;
    # Save different info here
    if($isAdmin) {
        # Save admin session stuff
        $_SESSION['Ausername']  = $username;
        $_SESSION['Auser_id']   = session_id();
        $_SESSION['Amycompany'] = $seleCompany;
    }
    else {
        # Create member session
        $_SESSION['username']  = $username;
        $_SESSION['user_id']   = $user_id;
        $_SESSION['mycompany'] = $seleCompany;
    }
    # Just save the status, not a message. On the redirected page, check
    # the status and write the message there. Don't store the message
    # to the session
    $_SESSION['success'] = true;
}
# Use session to store time, user can disable cookies
function expireTimeListener($exp=3600)
{
    # Now time
    $now = strtotime('now');
    # Create a future session expire time
    $future = $now+$exp;
    # If the user has just arrived at the site, create time
    if(!isset($_SESSION['ACTIVE_TIME']))
        $_SESSION['ACTIVE_TIME'] = $future;
    else {
        # If the current time is more that the stored time
        if($now > $_SESSION['ACTIVE_TIME']) {
            # First check if the user is logged in
            if(isset($_SESSION['usergroup'])) {
                # Destroy the session and redirect
                session_destroy();
                header('Location: /logout.php');
                exit;
            }
        }
        # If the current time is less than the future time, extend it
        $_SESSION['ACTIVE_TIME'] = $future;
    }
}
```

**/login.php**

```
# Include the functions
include_once(__DIR__.'/functions/myfunctions.php');
# Put this at the very top of your page, before everything else
session_start();
/**
* Do whatever here that generates the $row array
*/
# Set status here (string to lower for use later)
$status = strtolower($row["status"]);
# Verify that the status is a valid type
if(!in_array($status,array('admin','member')))
    # If not a valid type, set it to false for safety
    $status = false;
# Determine type
switch($status) {
    case('admin'):
        # Log in admin
        logInUser($username,$seleCompany,true);
        break;
    case('member'):
        # Log in member
        logInUser($username,$seleCompany);
        break;
    default:
        # Just save the status, not a message. On the redirected page, check
        # the status and write the message there. Don't store the message
        # to the session
        $_SESSION['warning'] = false;
}
# Create redirect path
$header = (!empty($_SESSION['warning']) && !empty($status))? "persol/{$status}/" : '';
# Redirect
header("Location: {$header}index.php");
# Stop execution
exit;
```

On your other pages that don't include the login, add the expire listener:

**/all_other_pages.php**

```
# Include the functions
include_once(__DIR__.'/functions/myfunctions.php');
# Add to very top
session_start();
# Add directly after your expiration function
expireTimeListener();
```

One note on numeric values for `usergroup` status a benefit to that is that you can use greater-than-equal-to to show admin status so for instance:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['usergroup'])) {
    if($_SESSION['usergroup'] <= 2)
        echo 'If you ever add a new usergroup type (like 3), every logged in user can see content who is Member (2) and Admin (1), but not greater (3 or higher).';
    elseif($_SESSION['usergroup'] >= 2)
        echo 'Only a member and lower status member can see content.';
    elseif($_SESSION['usergroup'] < 2)
        echo 'Only an admin can see content.';
}
else
    echo 'You\'re not logged in.';
```